# Why a specific temperature for value of 1 calorie?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, units

Everything in chemistry often comes with a strong reason and facts behind it, but I stuck in definition of $1$ calorie.

My reference book define one calorie as amount of heat required to raise the temperature of one gram of water from $14.5$ degrees Celsius to $15.5$ degrees Celsius.

Why $14.5$ and $15.5$, why temperature such as  $0$ to $1$ or $19$ to $20$ degree Celsius is not chosen?

Please forgive me if this question is too easy and I can't figure out the logic related to it.

I shall be glad to have your suggestions.

Comment: Those are close to room temperature. Using 0C runs the risk of getting some enthalpy of the phase transition mixed in.

Comment: i cant understand everything after room temperature

Comment: What happens to water at zero degrees C? How would that impact a thermodynamic measurement?

Comment: Now, the question of why not other temperature ranges - the Gibbs free energy of water is not constant vs. temperature, so the heat capacity varies with temperature. Thus, you must specify a specific temperature range.

Comment: That also is the reason it is so difficult to liquefy helium: at low temperatures the heat capacity drops, so that the slightest energy input warms it greatly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#/media/File:Heat_capacity_of_4He_01.jpg

Comment: jon but my question is why the specific temperature (you mentioned)is 14.5 to 15.5 degree celSius???

Comment: Lone Wolf, please do not readd the clutter that serves on purpose to the actual question. I have removed (and re-removed) it as part of [the site’s policy](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Instead of writing ‘thank you’ and thus cluttering up the question, say *thanks* by upvoting and/or accepting answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why temperature such as 0 or 1 degree celsius is not chosen??

That has been chosen by some.

According to [Physical Laboratory Experiments: Part III.--Heat, 4th edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=jHdKAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=15%20degree%20calorie&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6g_yIncbPAhVGND4KHT_KCNkQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=15%20degree%20calorie&f=false) (1912) :

> The following different calories should not be confused:
>
> 1. ZERO DEGREE CALORIE:- The quantity of heat required to raise one gram of water from 0 [degrees] C to 1 [degree] C.
> 2. ORDINARY CALORIE: cal.-The quantity of heat required to raise one gram of water from 15 [degrees] C to 16 [degree] C, this being taken as the mean room temperature.
> 3. MEAN CALORIE OR ICE CALORIMETER CALORIE: The one-hundred part of heat required to raise one gram of water from 0 [degrees] C to 100 [degrees] C.
> 4. ...

Heat capacity of liquid water is a continuously varying function of temperature itself, so a particular temperature or temperature interval must be specified.  Various intervals were chosen historically, and when a small interval near 15 degrees C is chosen it is because that was thought of as room temperature 100-200 years ago.

Comment: can you provide heat required (in joules) each time,i mean value of zero degree calorie,value of one degree calorie etc.

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/qui/caloresph2o.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Some measurements are easier than others. If you try to measure the heat capacity of water at $0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, you'll need to be awfully careful that ice melt doesn't alter the accuracy of your measurement. This is not a problem at a higher temperature like $15\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

Comment: what if i go to 20 or 30 degree celsius??

Comment: As @DavePhD pointed out, the heat capacity does vary as a function of temperature. You might get a different value. There's nothing that says you can't report that value or put it in a table, but it might be less useful if that doesn't fit your use case.